# How to fetch records which satisfy the query in wp8

Tags: c#, linq, windows-phone-8

I am working with a local database from the following link.
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ae35ca/working-with-creating-a-local-database-in-wp7/

Everything is working fine, but i cant fetch the item which age=15

```
public IList<Employee> GetEmployeeList()
{
    IList<Employee> EmployeeList = null;
    using (EmployeeDataContext Empdb = new EmployeeDataContext(strConnectionString)
    {
        IQueryable<Employee> EmpQuery = from Emp in Empdb.Employees select Emp;
        EmployeeList = EmpQuery.ToList();
    }
    return EmployeeList;
}
private void button4_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    IList<Employee> EmployeesList = this.GetEmployeeList();
    StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    strBuilder.AppendLine("Employee Details");
    foreach (Employee emp in EmployeesList)
    {
        strBuilder.AppendLine("Name - " + emp.EmployeeName + " Age - " + emp.EmployeeAge);
    }
    MessageBox.Show(strBuilder.ToString());
}
```

The above code fetch all records. But i need a query to fetch items only with age 15.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LINQ is lazy. It will only perform an actual DB fetch when it must.

When you call `.ToList` on an `IQueryable` you are forcing the DB to enumerate the results and thus fetching all the data from the database.

If you want the database to filter the results rather than the client - return an `IQueryable` from the `GetEmployeeList` method and filter that on the button click:

```
public IQueryable<Employee> GetEmployeeList()
{
    // the database should be available on the class here, don't dispose it
    // or this won't work since it'll be disposed before you make a query
    return (from Emp in Empdb.Employees select Emp);
}
private void button4_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var EmployeesList = this.GetEmployeeList();
    StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    strBuilder.AppendLine("Employee Details");
    // now we can filter it
    foreach (Employee emp in EmployeesList.Where(e => e.EmployeeAge == 15)) 
    {
        strBuilder.AppendLine("Name - " + emp.EmployeeName + " Age - " + emp.EmployeeAge);
    } 
    // this could also be nicer with string.Join
    MessageBox.Show(strBuilder.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It should just be a simple case of adding a `where` clause to your LINQ statement, so something like:

```
var EmpQuery = from Emp in Empdb.Employees where emp.EmployeeAge == 15 select Emp;
```